What is the correct commutation relationship of vector $\boldsymbol{r}$ and vector $\boldsymbol{p}$?
We choose $\boldsymbol{r}$ and $\boldsymbol{p}$ are 3 dim vector, and try to get $ [\boldsymbol{r},\boldsymbol{p}]$. In spherical coordinate system,
\begin{align*}
 [\boldsymbol{r},\boldsymbol{p}] f & = \boldsymbol{r}\cdot\boldsymbol{p}f-\boldsymbol{p}\cdot\boldsymbol{r}f \\
 & = -i\hbar\boldsymbol{r}\cdot\nabla f + i\hbar\nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{r}f \\
 & = -i\hbar\boldsymbol{r}\cdot\nabla f + i\hbar \boldsymbol{r} \cdot \nabla f + i\hbar f \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{r} \\
 & = i\hbar f \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{r}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
 \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{r} = \frac{1}{r^{2}} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} (r^{2}r) = 3
\end{align*}
so $ [\boldsymbol{r},\boldsymbol{p}] = 3i\hbar $. Or use another method
\begin{align*}
 [\boldsymbol{r},\boldsymbol{p}] = [r_{i}\boldsymbol{e}_{i},p_{j}\boldsymbol{e}_{j}] = 3i\hbar
\end{align*}
But there is a strange equation in my book
\begin{align*}
 [\boldsymbol{r},G(\boldsymbol{p})] = i\hbar \frac{\partial G}{\partial \boldsymbol{p}}
\end{align*}
I can't realize what is $ \frac{\partial}{\partial \boldsymbol{p}} $, but use it under
\begin{align*}
 [\boldsymbol{r},\boldsymbol{p}] =  i\hbar \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{p}}{\partial \boldsymbol{p}} = i\hbar
\end{align*}
So what is right, $ i\hbar $ or $ 3i\hbar $?
Thanks.

It looks like you got a paradox here because the commutator of vector-operators was not defined properly. Is it a scalar or a tensor quantity?

Stick in the indices you imply, and you should be all set.
